# Remove duplicates from PHP which has multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, advanced-custom-fields

This is the current output I have from an array by doing `var_dump($getvals)`:

```
array(2) {
  ["value"]=>string(5) "150mm"
  ["label"]=>string(5) "150mm"
}
array(2) {
  ["value"]=>string(5) "150mm"
  ["label"]=>string(5) "150mm"
}
array(2) {
  ["value"]=>string(5) "150mm"
  ["label"]=>string(5) "150mm"
}
array(2) {
  ["value"]=>string(5) "150mm"
  ["label"]=>string(5) "150mm"
}
array(2) {
  ["value"]=>string(5) "125mm"
  ["label"]=>string(5) "125mm"
}
array(2) {
  ["value"]=>string(5) "125mm"
  ["label"]=>string(5) "125mm"
}
```

What I want to achieve is first of all, to ignore the `['label']` tables and then try removing any duplicates (150mm and 125mm). I have tried both `array_unique` and `!inarray()` but it won't work. Here is my code:

```
$getvals = get_sub_field('option_diameter'); // This is my array
$takens = array(); // I create an empty array for later on
foreach ($getvals as $key => $getval){ // Running through the array
  if ($key == 'value'){ // Ignoring Label table
    if(!in_array($getval, $takens)){ // Check if the current value is already inside $takens array
      $takens[] = $getval; // If not, then put it
    }
  }
}
var_dump($takens); // The output is below
```

This is what I get from `var_dump($takens)` :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>string(5) "150mm"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>string(5) "150mm"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>string(5) "150mm"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>string(5) "150mm"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>string(5) "125mm"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>string(5) "125mm"
}
```

The duplicate values are not removed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first fetch `value` by using [array_diff_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php). Then you need to use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), in which passing null as second parameter and unique by value as key to removing duplicates(as keys can not be duplicated). Then to reset indexes [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Here is the script,

```
$takens = array_values(array_column(array_map(function ($a) {
    return array_diff_key($a, ['label' => '']);
}, $getvals), null, 'value'));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/D23iN)

**Output:-**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "150mm"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "125mm"
  }
}
```

Comment: $a is inner iterator of array_map, $getvals this is your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_column`

```
 $r = array_values(array_column($a, null, 'label'));
```

OR

if you want to keep single column

```
$r = array_values(array_column($a, 'value', 'label'));
print_r($r);
```

`array_values` will reorder the keys of the array

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/n8SA1

Comment: Will this remove the duplicates from the array?

Comment: @dominotrix why not.:)

Comment: Array()Array()Array()Array()Array()Array()
That's all I got.

Comment: @dominotrix visit the link provided

Comment: I dont think your $a array is the same as the one i posted ($getvals).

Answer (score 0):

Use a key to remove the duplicate, [Demo](https://3v4l.org/5AW7Z)

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $arr){
    $result[$arr['value']] = $arr;
}
print_r(array_values($result));
```

Comment: @dominotrix check the demo. I cannot see your demo, so I cannot figure out the issue with your code.

Comment: I checked your demo of course, but the demo array you have is not the same as mine. The structure is different. Your code works for your array only - sadly not for mine. You think my array structure is wrong somehow?

Comment: I use the structure in your question.

Comment: If the structure in your quesion is not the same as your's. Please edit it with what really you're using.

Comment: The one i posted is the output of my array when i do `var_dump`. Did you actually copy-paste my array into 3v4L ? Cause it seems different.

Answer (score 0):

It look like you forgot a foreach.
Here a test done a few minutes ago :

```
$aArrayTest = array (
            array(
                'value'=>'150mm',
                'label'=>'150mm'
            ), 
            array(
                'value'=>'150mm',
                'label'=>'150mm'
            ),
            array(
                'value'=>'150mm',
                'label'=>'150mm'
            ),
            array(
                'value'=>'150mm',
                'label'=>'150mm'
            ),
            array(
                'value'=>'125mm',
                'label'=>'125mm'
            ),
            array(
                'value'=>'125mm',
                'label'=>'125mm'
            )
        );
```

`$aArrayResult = array();
    foreach ($aArrayTest as $aArray) { // Running through the array of Arrays
        foreach ($aArray as $key => $value){ // Running through each array
            if ($key == 'value'){ // Ignoring Label table
                if(!in_array($value, $aArrayResult)){ // Check if the current value is already inside $takens array
                    $aArrayResult[] = $value; // If not, then put it
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var_dump($aArrayResult);</pre>`